# Update nested array value in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my `database structure`

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("58243c430386650d78d12d53"),
"email" : "technotest91@gmail.com",
"dentistName" : "Suzuka",
"tempDetails" : [ 
    {
        "tempName" : "Elsa",
        "city" : "bangalore",
         "tempEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
        "experience" : "5",    
        "hiredDates" : [ 
            {
                "status" : "Accepted",
                "bookingId" : "36Y0YM",
            }
        ],
    }, 
    {
        "tempName" : "Elsa",  
        "city" : "bangalore",
         "tempEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
        "experience" : "5",   
        "hiredDates" : [ 
            {

                "status" : "Hired",
                "bookingId" : "92Qhd7",
            }
        ],  
    }, 
    {
        "tempName" : "Elsa",  
        "city" : "bangalore",
        "experience" : "5",
        "tempEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
        "typeOfPractice" : "Oral Surgery",
        "hiredDates" : [ 
            {
                "status" : "Hired",
                "bookingId" : "95kTe9",
            }
        ],
    }
]
 }
```

I am trying to update the `Status` based on the `bookingId`. I am not able to update the value . I have tried the following code in `JAVA MONGODB` but it does not seem to be updating.

```
    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();

    List<BasicDBObject> andQuery = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    andQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("email", dentalEmail));
    andQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("tempDetails.tempEmail",tempEmail));


    searchQuery.put("$and", andQuery);

    DBCursor cursor = col.find(searchQuery);
     if (cursor.count() != 0) {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {

        BasicDBList jobStatusList = (BasicDBList) cursor.next().get("tempDetails");

            for(int k=0;k<jobStatusList.size();k++)
            {
                BasicDBObject tempJobObject = (BasicDBObject) jobStatusList.get(k);

                BasicDBList hiredDatesList = (BasicDBList) tempJobObject.get("hiredDates");


                for(int i =0; i<hiredDatesList.size();i++)
                {
                    BasicDBObject hiredDatesObject = (BasicDBObject) hiredDatesList.get(i);
                    String dbBookingId = hiredDatesObject.getString("bookingId");

                    if(dbBookingId.equalsIgnoreCase(bookingId))
                    {
                        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("$set",
                                new BasicDBObject().append("tempDetails."+k+".hiredDates."+i+".status", status));

                        col.update(searchQuery, doc, false, false);

                        System.out.println(doc);

                    }else{
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
```

Kindly help me out with this issue as I have been struggling to update the record based on the `BookingId`. I get the document through a query and iterate over the objects and if the bookingid matches I am updating the record. Kindly help let me know what I should be changing..

Comment: Kindly add the code where you are "iterating over the objects and if the bookingid matches you are updating the record". Also, post the full stack trace if there are any errors you are getting

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Hey there are no errors. I'm adding the code right now.

Comment: When you use the printed search & update and put em in a shell command does it update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked your database properly ? I am able to run your code perfectly fine without errors and it does update the collection as well.

I just created a method where i am doing the following :

```
private void performOperation() {
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("vinay");

    logger.info("connected successfully");

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();

    List<BasicDBObject> andQuery = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    andQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("email", "technotest91@gmail.com"));
    andQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("tempDetails.tempEmail", "abc@gmail.com"));

    searchQuery.put("$and", andQuery);

    logger.info("executing :"+ searchQuery);

    DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);
    if (cursor.count() != 0) {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {

            BasicDBList jobStatusList = (BasicDBList) cursor.next().get("tempDetails");

            for (int k = 0; k < jobStatusList.size(); k++) {
                BasicDBObject tempJobObject = (BasicDBObject) jobStatusList.get(k);

                BasicDBList hiredDatesList = (BasicDBList) tempJobObject.get("hiredDates");

                for (int i = 0; i < hiredDatesList.size(); i++) {
                    BasicDBObject hiredDatesObject = (BasicDBObject) hiredDatesList.get(i);
                    String dbBookingId = hiredDatesObject.getString("bookingId");

                    if (dbBookingId.equalsIgnoreCase("36Y0YM")) {
                        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject()
                                .append("tempDetails." + k + ".hiredDates." + i + ".status", "New Status"));

                        table.update(searchQuery, doc, false, false);

                        logger.info(doc);

                    } else {
                        logger.info("no record find");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after i execute this the status where booking ID is 36Y0YM get updated to - "New Status".

But i noticed one this. the way you wrote the loops... because even after the record is updated it iterates again and prints the message "no record found" in your case it will set the result to false, so if you relying on the result then your whole approach would be wrong.

i dont know what logic you are trying to build but the point is there is nothing wrong in your code which updates records in mongodb if there is anything wrong its the loops your wrote.

Comment: hey yea I just noticed that while I was debugging my code. Reason that was happening is because I need to set the flag to true after the update. I've fixed it now.. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: if you feel my suggestion worked you can accept my answer or flag it. thanks